# SQL Server Express connection

Tags: delphi, sql-server-express

When I try to build a connection string (dbGO ADO) in Delphi and use user name and password to connect to a SQL Server Express database using Native SQL client 11, I get "connection successful" however when I click OK to save the connection string it automatically reverts to a blank password.

I tried to define the connection string in Before Connect event however it keeps saying login incorrect and the credentials are correct.

If I enable login prompt the connection works fine after inserting the password.

Is there a way to avoid using the login prompt?

PS the database is on my desktop at home and I try to connect to it from work. I can make an account with a blank password in which case everything works with no login prompt enabled however I would like to have a password.

SOLVED:
The solution to this problem is to set the  Persist Security Info  to true thnks TLama

Comment: a) Which Provider are you using to build the connection string and have you ticked the Allow Saving Password in the connection-uilding pop-up dialog.  b) Have you set the LoginPrompt property of your AdoConnection to false?  If the Connection String and AdoConnection are correctly set up, you should not have to see a Login pop-up at r/time.

Comment: This is by design for security. You should be dynamically assigning the connection string in run-time.

Comment: You can set [`Persist Security Info`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214039(v=sql.80).aspx) to `true` in your connection string.

Comment: What does your ConnectionString look like. I use dbGO, and in the TADOConnection.BeforeConnect event, I have: ADOConnection1.ConnectionString := 'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MyUserName;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;Data Source=MyServerName;Password=MyPassword;Network Library=dbmssocn;';